# Parse Date From Querystring on VisualForce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, date

I'm trying to pass a `date` from the querystring to a `component` on a `visualforce` page.

with a url like this: `salesforce.com/apex/mypage?mydate=2013-05-30`

I thought it would be as simple as this:

```
<apex:page>
     <c:myComponent myDate="{!date.valueof($CurrentPage.parameters.mydate)}" />
</apex:page>
```

but I'm getting an error when trying to save my `visualforce` page:

```
    Error: Unknown function date.valueof. Check spelling
```

What am I doing wrong? How do you pass a `date` to a `component` on a `visualforce` page via the querystring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the date.valueof is an Apex syntax not visualforce.
You could instead use

```
<c:myComponent myDate="{!datevalue($CurrentPage.parameters.mydate)}" />
```

This will work in parsing out the date in the format you have it. For instance ?mydate=2013-03-04 parses out for me as Mon Mar 04 00:00:00 GMT 2013
Or alternatively, if your component has a controller then you could pass the parameter through as a String and parse it there. This would give you some more control over dealing with badly formatted or missing data.